# Top-level Bool encoded as number property list fragment. PropertyListEncoder

Tags: swift, boolean, nsuserdefaults

I have this generic function to save in NSUserDefaults, in generally works but now I want to save a boolean value and I get an error. I could not find anything and I do not understand why it is not working.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func saveUserDefaults<T: Codable>(withKey key: String, myType: T) throws{
        do {
            let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(myType)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
            print("Saved for Key:", key)
        } catch let error {

            print("Save Failed")
            throw error
        }
    }
```

I am calling it like this:

```
try! UserDefaults().saveUserDefaults(withKey: "String", myType: false)
```

This is the error I get. I know there is an other way to save boolean values, but I am wondering why it is not working like this?

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.EncodingError.invalidValue(false,
>   Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
>   "Top-level Bool encoded as number property list fragment.",
>   underlyingError: nil))

Thanks!

Comment: A property list always requires a dictionary or array as top-level object, compare https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization.

Comment: Is that not why I set the key?

Comment: `false` is a boolean, not a dictionary. It would also fail with an integer or a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PropertyListEncoder` encodes to a “property list,” and that is always an
array or a dictionary, compare [PropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization).

Therefore

```
let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(myType)
```

fails if `myType` is a `Bool` (or anything which is not an array
or a dictionary).

The possible objects in a property list are also restricted, they can only be instances of
`NSData`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSDate`, or `NSNumber` – or of Swift types
which are bridged to one of those Foundation types.

Answer (score 2):

As @Martin said a PropertyListEncoder supports only property lists on top level, but not a single fragment of property list like NSNumber.
A very simple (though not very elegant) workaround is to wrap any object into array:

```
let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode([myType])
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
```

And decode it as:

```
let arr = try  PropertyListDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data)
return arr.first
```

see https://www.marisibrothers.com/2018/07/workaround-for-serializing-codable-fragments.html

Comment: this is really useful!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to encode a Boolean value to save into UserDefaults. You can directly save the boolean into the UserDefaults by calling

```
    let myValue: Bool = false
    UserDefaults.standard.set(myValue, forKey: "key")
```

See Apple docs: [UserDefaults.set(_:forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1408905-set).

In fact, Float, Double, Integer, Bool and URL types do not need to be encoded and can directly be saved to UserDefaults.

I see that you have a function that takes a Codable type, encodes it and then saves it to UserDefaults. As Martin R pointed out, you will have to modify that function and check whether passed object can be directly saved to UserDefaults without a need for encoding. It is not necessarily pretty but something like this could work:

```
switch objectToSave {
  case let aFloatType as Float:
    UserDefaults.standard.set(aFloatType, forKey: "key")
  case let aDoubleType as Double:
    UserDefaults.standard.set(aDoubleType, forKey: "key")
  case let anIntegerType as Int:
    UserDefaults.standard.set(anIntegerType, forKey: "key")
  case let aBoolType as Bool:
    UserDefaults.standard.set(aBoolType, forKey: "key")
  case let aURLType as URL:
    UserDefaults.standard.set(aURLType, forKey: "key")
  default:
    //encode the object as a PropertyList and then save it to UserDefaults
    do {
        let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(objectToSave)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
    } catch let error {
        //the object you passed cannot be encoded as a PropertyList
        //possibly because the object cannot be represented as
        //NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary - or equivalent Swift types
        //also contents of NSArray and NSDictionary have to be one of the types above
        print("Save Failed: \(error)")
        //perform additional error handling
    }
}
```